# QR Bitmap in ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, qr-code, zxing

I am trying to generate a QR code using the library QRgen which is based on another library, ZXing and adding the generated QR code as a bitmap to an ImageView:

```
public void generate(View view){   
    Bitmap bmp = QRCode.from("heya").bitmap();
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);        
}
```

and the XML file for the ImageView is:

```
<ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false" />
```

I don't get any compiler errors, but the image won't appear to the ImageView. Could you please help me sort this out?

Comment: Try to set image bitmap with a drawable resource to understand if the problem is on the QRCode generation ( you can also watch in debug the content of bmp variable ) or in image change

Comment: It's not on the generation of the code. I tried it with a file as well and it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Where you run the function generate?